# Absolute newbie - first function question

Tags: javascript, function

Just started learning JS and have a question on my first function.

I am trying to add an image overlay to another image based on the condition of the text content of an h4 tag.

I am getting an error: null is not an object (evaluating ‘textStatus.textContent’)

```
const textStatus = document.querySelector('h4.status');
const statusText = textStatus.textContent;
const mainImage = document.querySelector('.main-image');

function statusSnipe(){
    if(statusText === "Rental Status: Rented"){
        mainImage.classList.add('rental-snipe-rented');
    };
};
statusSnipe();
```

As I said this is my first function - I look forward to your replies.

Comment: please provide your html code.

Comment: Hi... Welcome tô stackoverflow ...  Join the community ...  it is always better that the title of your post mention what you really need.   How to do THIS....   JS...  with this you will probabbly receive a faster feedback..  very welcome

Comment: Hi. I know this is your first function to overlay a image on another element, but this can be done in CSS with absolute position OR a background url image. Is there a reason this needs to be done in JS?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will create better subject lines from now on.

Comment: I am actually adding the image via css - by trying to add a class to the image container via the function in question. The test site is here: http://www.j2studio.com/grg3910/properties-for-rent/6121-louisiana-ave-new-port-richey-fl-34653

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the querySelector didn't find an element matching `h4.status` and returned [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null). The next line then attempts to access `textContent` on `null` and fails.

If your script is in the `<head>` of the document it will execute before the rest of your document loads, which would account for the scenario described above: When the querySelector runs, the `<h4>` isn't in the document yet.

You could fix this by moving your script to the end of the body or by listening for a [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) before executing.

Comment: Thanks, Ray. Yes it is in the head section. So I added the following code, which does not throw any errors, but just doesn't work.

  ```  
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const textStatus = document.querySelector('h4.status');
    const statusText = textStatus.textContent;
    const mainImage = document.querySelector('.main-image');

    function statusSnipe(){
        if(statusText === "Rental Status: Available"){
            mainImage.classList.add('rental-snipe-rented');
        };
    };
    });

````

Comment: can't seem to format the code properly in the comment

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/yd13kcet/). It's using your code inside the event listener and it works. I added some console logging of variables along the way, but it's otherwise lifted directly from your example.

Comment: Checked your fiddle and I am getting console errors in Safari and Chrome. I saw a brief flash of red at one point but I do not see the class added to main-image div?

Comment: I noticed after I commented that my fiddle runs if you hit the run button but throws an error when the page (the entire fiddle page) first loads. Seems like that might be an issue with trying to listen for load events within a framed environment but I can't say for sure and I need to step out for a bit. I'll check in again when I get back.

Comment: I tried it on CodePen without the listener as well, but was unsuccessful. https://codepen.io/jjspelman/pen/pojpgJr

Comment: Your codepen works for me. The class gets added to the image. The reason you don't see any change is because an <img> is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), and replaced elements can't have css pseudo elements like `::before` or `::after`. But if you look at the img element in the devtools the class is there.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Got it to work. I added the event listener as Ray suggested, and moved the function invoke to *within* the event listener and it works. Thank you for all your input. Now I need to figure a way to create if/else or switch statements to add different image overlays for "Available" and "On Hold".

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  
const textStatus = document.querySelector('h4.status');
    // const statusText = textStatus.textContent;
    const mainImage = document.querySelector('.main-image');

    function statusSnipe(){
        if(textStatus.innerText === "Rental Status: Rented"){
            mainImage.classList.add('rental-snipe-rented');
        }
        else if(textStatus.innerText === "Rental Status: On Hold"){
            mainImage.classList.add('rental-snipe-hold');
        } else {};
    }
statusSnipe();
});
```

```css
.main-image {position: relative;}
.rental-snipe-rented::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url("http://www.j2studio.com/grg3910/images/new-rented-snipe.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 z-index:9;
}
.rental-snipe-hold::before {
content: '';
background-image: url("http://www.j2studio.com/grg3910/images/on-hold-snipe.png");
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index:9;
}
.rental-status-text {color: #aaa;}
```

```html
<div class="tm-grid-expand uk-grid-margin uk-grid" uk-grid="">
<div class="uk-width-2-3@m uk-first-column">
    
        
            
            
                
<div data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-0-1" class="main-image uk-margin uk-text-center uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
        <img class="el-image uk-box-shadow-large" alt="" src="http://www.j2studio.com/grg3910/templates/yootheme/cache/Living1-76731dac.jpeg">    
    
</div>

            
        
    
</div>

<div class="uk-width-1-3@m">
    
        
            
            
                
<h4 class="status uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-0" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">        <span class="rental-status-text">Rental Status: </span>On Hold    </h4>
<h2 class="uk-h2 uk-margin-remove-vertical uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-1" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">        <sup>$</sup>950<sup>/mth</sup>    </h2><div class="uk-margin uk-width-medium@m uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-2" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">Spacious 3 Bedroom/1 Bathroom Home - No Carpet - Updated Kitchen - Inside Utility - Pet Friendly!</div>
<div data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-3" class="uk-margin">
    <div class="uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-1@m uk-child-width-1-1@l uk-child-width-1-1@xl uk-grid-row-small uk-grid-match uk-grid uk-grid-stack" uk-grid="">        <div class="uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg id="f5c2a82f-a8ae-474e-9bef-87f89d00969d" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="af4b105e-d1a5-49c8-ba95-4c7b70b26c69" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="aadd5cd5-ccc4-4f5c-b030-67875e2a080b" data-name="Layer 3"><path d="M9.49,22.52h7.78l.38-.55-.54-.38V19.9H9.49v-.75h7.66v-.44l3.69-4.87V7.32H18.48V8.46h-.76V7.32h-2V8.46H15V7.32H13V8.46h-.76V7.32h-2V8.46H9.53V7.32H7.16v18.5H20.85V22l-2,.79-.54-.38-.61.87H9.49Zm11-1.18-1.53.6-1.05-.74V19.56l2.55,1.78Zm-2.37-2.58,5.64-7.46,2.5,1.76-5.07,7.85Zm6.13-8L26.6,12.4a1.69,1.69,0,0,0-.29-2.14,1.71,1.71,0,0,0-2.1.46ZM27,13.28l-5.37,8.31v5H6.4v-20H9.53V5.42h.76V6.56h2V5.42H13V6.56h2V5.42h.76V6.56h2V5.42h.76V6.56h3.13v6.27l1.64-2.16c.8-1.07,2.26-1.89,3.5-1s1,2.54.23,3.64ZM16.71,14.43,16.27,14v2.51H11.74V14l-.43.41-.52-.55,3-2.76.26-.24.26.24,3,2.76-.52.55Zm-1.19-1.11v2.45h-3V13.32L14,11.91Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg> <strong>Date Available:</strong>  14 May 2020</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        <div class="uk-grid-margin uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg id="b83822a7-14c4-449a-bffa-a9b54d2aca77" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="bf7f72a3-79a5-4e4b-bc33-1c2a0d18bd51" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="af72ee32-b475-4a80-9f1f-4041cb45286d" data-name="Layer 1"><path d="M10.32,17.41H7.81v2.51h2.51Zm17.45-4.27V22.8H18.09V16.57H13.91V22.8H4.23V13.14H12l4-4.28,4,4.28ZM4.59,12.3h7L16,7.64l4.39,4.66h7L21.18,5.2H10.81Zm24,.09V23.64H17.25V17.41h-2.5v6.23H3.39V12.39l7-8H21.56l7.05,8Zm-4.42,5H21.68V19.9h2.51V17.41Zm.84-.84H20.84v4.19H25V16.55Zm-13.87,0v4.19H7V16.57Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>  <strong>Residence Type: </strong>Single Family</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        <div class="uk-grid-margin uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="a926b529-8e3b-4a85-b852-f16bccf15968" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="f1687f64-ca8f-4abb-9535-fab97947c724" data-name="Layer 1"><path d="M22.64,13.27a5,5,0,0,0-3.13-.87,5,5,0,0,0-3.13.87v.46h6.26v-.46Zm4.14,9.42H5.23v1.68H4.46v-5.1L8.59,14V7.63h.77V9.17H22.64V7.63h.77V14l4.13,5.28v5.1h-.76V22.69ZM5.23,21.93H26.78V19.78H5.23v2.15Zm10.39-8.2v-.46a5,5,0,0,0-3.13-.87,5,5,0,0,0-3.13.87v.46ZM26.37,19,22.84,14.5H9.16L5.63,19ZM22.64,9.94v2.4a6.57,6.57,0,0,0-3.13-.7,6.08,6.08,0,0,0-3.51.95,6.08,6.08,0,0,0-3.51-.95,6.57,6.57,0,0,0-3.13.7V9.94Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg> <strong>Bedrooms: </strong>3</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        <div class="uk-grid-margin uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg id="aacfd61b-f492-4e96-b3c7-9594675cd011" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="ec7019f1-cb29-4191-8955-9e1cf3b7e618" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="bacb411f-8d14-4e9e-af06-8af666522762" data-name="Layer 4"><path d="M5.88,15.27,11.36,17a18,18,0,0,0,5.78.89h9.6l-.09.45-1,4.78a2.88,2.88,0,0,1-2.87,2.54h-.66l.61,1.39-.68.3-.74-1.69H11.39l-.74,1.69-.69-.3.61-1.39H9.92A2.89,2.89,0,0,1,7,23.16L5.4,15.7l-.14-.63Zm6.48-4.94h-.75v5h.75Zm2.69,1H14.3v4.55h.75V11.33Zm2.69,0H17V16h.74V11.33Zm2.7-1h-.75v5.73h.75Zm-4-7.72V6.5h6.23v.75H20.74A4.55,4.55,0,0,1,19,9.07a6,6,0,0,1-6,0,4.5,4.5,0,0,1-1.72-1.82H9.41V6.5h6.24V2.61Zm3.48,4.64H12.17a3.81,3.81,0,0,0,1.25,1.18,5.2,5.2,0,0,0,5.21,0,3.81,3.81,0,0,0,1.25-1.18Zm-8.74,10.5L6.27,16.18,7.77,23a2.15,2.15,0,0,0,2.15,2H22.78a2.13,2.13,0,0,0,2.14-2l.9-4.34H17.14a19.07,19.07,0,0,1-6-.91Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg> <strong>Bathrooms: </strong>1</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        <div class="uk-grid-margin uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg id="f66d02d0-648e-4973-b0d6-03149c0e4a34" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="b586850a-7579-41cd-85fe-2df77250fb87" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="a5c19eb4-9dd9-4d22-976a-05512768b0ac" data-name="Layer 1"><path d="M6.05,5.63H26.37V26.37H5.63V5.63ZM25.52,19.79H13.32v5.73h12.2Zm-13,0h-6v5.73h6Zm-6-.85h19V13.06h-19Zm0-6.73h12.2V6.48H6.48v5.73Zm13.05,0h6V6.48h-6Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>  <strong> Square Feet: </strong>1088</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        <div class="uk-grid-margin uk-first-column">
<div class="el-item uk-panel uk-margin-remove-first-child uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
                        
                    

        
        
        
    
        
        
                <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-top"><svg id="b59345cd-3c40-4504-a86e-a520304b6ed6" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="b7e5b9e6-f457-499e-893b-2e586346f98b" data-name="Layer 2"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#2d9546"></circle></g><g id="a41873e6-b1f3-47ac-8451-f911d2ed1890" data-name="Layer 3"><path d="M9.3,13.94a6.58,6.58,0,0,1-1.77-3.18,10.07,10.07,0,0,1-.12-4.37l.1-.51L8,6.11l2.47,1.25a4.68,4.68,0,0,1,3.09,0L16,6.11l.46-.23.09.51a10.41,10.41,0,0,1,.15,2.84,9.22,9.22,0,0,1-.57,2.48,15.33,15.33,0,0,0,2.67,4.07c1.94,2.37,3.95,4.82,3.7,9.19,3-3,1.55-6.45.19-9.77a15.54,15.54,0,0,1-1.54-5.58h.77a15.25,15.25,0,0,0,1.48,5.29c1.55,3.78,3.15,7.69-1,11.21H7v-.47c0-.76,0-2.89,2.33-3.23V13.94Zm-1-3.38A5.69,5.69,0,0,0,10,13.47l.14.12v9.54H9.74a2,2,0,0,0-2,2,1.48,1.48,0,0,0,0,.21h14c.38-4.35-1.59-6.76-3.5-9.08a15.72,15.72,0,0,1-2.86-4.43l-.05-.14.06-.14A8.32,8.32,0,0,0,16,9.14,9.6,9.6,0,0,0,15.87,7L13.72,8.12l-.15.08-.16-.06A4,4,0,0,0,12,7.87a4,4,0,0,0-1.44.27l-.16.06-.15-.08L8.09,7a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,.18,3.56Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg> <strong>Pets Allowed? </strong>conditional</div>        
        
        
        
        
    
</div></div>
        </div>

</div>

<div data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-4" class="uk-margin uk-text-center uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">
    
    
        
        
<a class="el-content uk-button uk-button-default" title="Apply now." href="/grg3910/rental-application">

        <span uk-icon="pencil" class="uk-icon"><svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-svg="pencil"><path fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M17.25,6.01 L7.12,16.1 L3.82,17.2 L5.02,13.9 L15.12,3.88 C15.71,3.29 16.66,3.29 17.25,3.88 C17.83,4.47 17.83,5.42 17.25,6.01 L17.25,6.01 Z"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M15.98,7.268 L13.851,5.148"></path></svg></span>
    
    <span class="uk-text-middle">Apply Now!</span>

    

</a>


        
    
    
</div>
<div class="uk-margin-remove-vertical uk-text-center uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-5" uk-scrollspy-class="" style="">More Details Below</div><div data-id="template-rWLyq4-M#0-1-1-6" class="detailsbutton uk-margin-remove-vertical uk-text-center uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-scale-up" uk-scrollspy-class="uk-animation-scale-up" style=""><a class="uk-icon-link uk-icon" uk-icon="icon: chevron-down; width: 40;" href="#details" uk-scroll=""><svg width="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-svg="chevron-down"><polyline fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.03" points="16 7 10 13 4 7"></polyline></svg></a></div>
            
        
    
</div>
</div>
```

r

test site: 
    http://www.j2studio.com/grg3910/properties-for-rent/6121-louisiana-ave-new-port-richey-fl-34653